Initial Connection takes 42 seconds
Started a new job and was handed the website. It's WordPress and supervisor said images were slowing the site down. They were needlessly large but I quickly realised that wasn't the issue (though I resized them to appease boss). In Chrome's network panel, it shows Initial Connection of 42.11 seconds. It's not images or even javascript when I look at the waterfall image. It's just the main document and then it all loads. When I enter the URL for the website admin panel, it also loads slowly. Does this make it likely to be a server resource issue? Or a process slowing things down?


you'll need to profile the server side of things to find out the answer to this, it isn't something you can figure out from just the browser dev tools. Take a look at plugins such as query monitor, or server tech such as xdebug. Also be extremely wary of plugins such as autoptimise that trash time to first byte on slow sites. Right now there's no way to answer this with just what you've provided, it's not really a question but an open ended investigation

First I would visit a single file in the browser, like an image file, to see if the server loads that quickly or not. If the image loads slowly, you will know it is a server speed problem. But if the image is fine, most likely there will be a PHP code slowing the website down, coming from a plugin or the theme.
You could use Health Check & Troubleshooting plugin to try to find the problematic plugin/theme quickly. Go to the Plugins list and click on "Troubleshoot" at one of the plugins. This turns off all other plugins and switches to a default WordPress Twenty[X] theme if there is one available, but only for your user, so the real website stays as it was. On the Plugins list you can turn on plugins one-by-one (or a couple together) with "Enable while troubleshooting", and this way you could see if there is a plugin involved in this matter. If the plugins are fine, at the top admin bar within "Troubleshooting Mode" you can select the original theme in "Themes", to see if that makes the website slow.
